Mean Reciprocal Rank (MRR) understanding for predicting top k elements
I have the following code from a paper, who have implemented MRR for recommending top-k elements using some Machine Learning model.
def MRR(test_y, pred_y, k=5):
    predict = pd.DataFrame([])
    predict["pred_y"] = pred_y
    predict["y"] = test_y

    predict = predict.sort_values("pred_y", ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
    predict["pred_y_rank_index"] = (predict.index) + 1
    predict = predict.sort_values("y", ascending=False)

    return sum(1 / predict["pred_y_rank_index"][:k]) / k

What I am not understanding is - how MRR works here according to the code. I understood MRR from this Wikipedia link. But when I'm predicting the top 5 elements, in the best case scenario, if the predicted elements' and actual elements' ranking matches 100%, in that case, shouldn't the MRR produce the result 1? But according to this code, the result of the top 5 (k=5) element would be ((1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + 1/5)/5) = 0.4566.
Now according to my understanding, either the code is implementing MRR in an incorrect way in this case or, MRR is not the right metric to evaluate this scenario. Any knowledge or thoughts on this would be highly appreciated.

These are the ranks for different queries, if the predictions are all correct, all ranks would be 1 and MRR would be 1 as you'd expected. I guess your second intuition is correct and MRR is not the correct measure for this scenario.
